# Adding people to a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to replace the 3 kids by using the package `\usepackage{tikzpeople}`
and I need to add `\faFileTextO` where are the fruits are placed.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{boy.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl1) at (0,5)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl) at (0,10)
{\includegraphics[width=.150\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};





\node[inner sep=0pt] (tangerine) at (10,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{tangerine.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (grapes) at (10,3)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{grapes.png}};
%%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
   ;
\node[inner sep=0pt] (strawberry) at (10,6)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{strawberry.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (pera) at (10,9)
 {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{pera.png}};

\draw[-latex,thick,blue] (girl1) -- (strawberry);


\draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) to[out=-120,in=120] (boy.west);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (pera);
\draw[-latex,thick,blue] (boy) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick,blue,fill=blue] (boy) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (tangerine);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (pera);
\draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (tangerine);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried this code, but it doe not look good:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0){\faFileTextO};

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (girl1) at (0,5){\faFileTextO};

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (girl) at (0,10){\faFileTextO};





    \node[inner sep=0pt] (tangerine) at (10,0){\faFileTextO};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (grapes) at (10,3){\faFileTextO};
    %%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
    ;
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (strawberry) at (10,6){\faFileTextO};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (pera) at (10,9){\faFileTextO};

    \draw[-latex,thick,blue] (girl1) -- (strawberry);


    \draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) to[out=-120,in=120] (boy.west);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (grapes);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (strawberry);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (pera);
    \draw[-latex,thick,blue] (boy) -- (strawberry);
    \draw[-latex,thick,blue,fill=blue] (boy) -- (grapes);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (tangerine);
    \draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (pera);
    \draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (tangerine);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Er ... so what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to add the people where the jpg image is located.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Have you tried substituting the file icon (for which you already know the command) for the fruit? You just put the things into the nodes where you want them in place of the things you don't want. I'm not seeing the difficulty. (Particularly for the file symbol, where there's no possible question of nesting.)

Comment: You could use Ti*k*Zlings instead of the people. They will take care of the fruits. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have tried `\usepackage{fontawesome}` package and `\faFileTextO` but it does not work

Comment: This is because you wrap it into `\includegraphics`. Instead of e.g. `\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{\faFileTextO}};` use `\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
    {\faFileTextO};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cfr says, there is no problem in replacing what you have by what you want to have. This is to answer the question why your code does not work. This is because you wrap `\includegraphics` around symbols from `fontawesome`. Instead of e.g.

```
\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{\faFileTextO}};
```

you should use

```
\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy) at (0,0) {\faFileTextO};
```

Here is the MWE with these corrections and with `tikzpeople` nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,nodes={scale=3},every label/.append
    style={scale={0.5}}]

    \node[inner sep=0pt,bob] (boy)  at (0,0)
    {};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,alice] (girl1) at (0,5)
    {};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,alice] (girl) at (0,10)
    {};





    \node[inner sep=0pt,label=below:1] (tangerine) at (10,0)
    {\faFileTextO};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,label=below:2] (grapes) at (10,3)
    {\faFileTextO};
    %%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
    ;
    \node[inner sep=0pt,label=below:3] (strawberry) at (10,6)
    {\faFileTextO};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,label=below:4] (pera) at (10,9)
    {\faFileTextO};

    \draw[-latex,thick,blue] (girl1) -- (strawberry);


    \draw[<->,thick] (girl.west) to[out=-120,in=120] (boy.west);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (grapes);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (strawberry);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (pera);
    \draw[-latex,thick,blue] (boy) -- (strawberry);
    \draw[-latex,thick,blue,fill=blue] (boy) -- (grapes);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (girl) -- (tangerine);
    \draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (pera);
    \draw[latex-,dashed,thick] (boy) -- (tangerine);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Chapeau!!! Is there any chance to put a label below each document, like Document 1, Document 2 and Document 3?

Comment: @NaveganTeX Yes, sure. I added them. (Some care has to be taken since I scale all nodes, and labels are also nodes, so one needs to undo the overall scaling with `every label`, see the code.)