# Code compiling forever in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am running the following code and it does not work, it keep compiling. 
The plot is related to this post and credits to [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513004/185467)
I just want to replace all the figures by `tikzpeople` and `{\faFileTextO}`

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKS:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 44mm,
start chain = A going below,
every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2mm, rounded corners,
    text width=0.15\linewidth,
    on chain=A},
arr/.style = {color=#1, ultra thick, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
 % I want to add bob, alice  here 
\node   {\includegraphics{girl.jpg}};    % A-1
\node   {\includegraphics{girl.jpg}};
\node   {\includegraphics{boy.jpg}};   % A-3
%
\node[above right=of A-1.east]
 %I want to add {\faFileTextO} here
{\includegraphics{pera.png}};         % A-4
\node   {\includegraphics{grapes.png}};
\node   {\includegraphics{strawberry.png}};
\node   {\includegraphics{naranja.jpeg}};    % A-7
%


\draw[red, ultra thick,
{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}
]  (A-4.east) to [bend left=45] (A-6.east);    


\foreach \i in {4,6,7}
\draw[arr=black] (A-1.east) -- (A-\i);

\draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-4);
\draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-6);
\foreach \i in {6}
\draw[arr=purple!50!gray] (A-3.east) -- (A-\i);
%
\draw[arr=orange,densely dashed] (A-4) -- (A-3);
%\draw[arr=brown,densely dashed] (A-7) -- (A-3);

\draw[arr=orange, ultra thick,dashed,
{}-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}
]  (A-7) to [bend left=45] (A-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Commands like `\node[inner sep=0pt,alice]` are wrong, it should be something like `\node[inner sep=0pt,alice]{};`.

Comment: And your code is an example for why I do not think it is a good idea to use `chains` wherever one may use it, similar comments apply to `quotes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code where I fixed the nodes. Another thing that had to be fixed is that, because labels are also nodes, the chain was screwed up. `chains` *can* be useful, but personally I do not think one should use them at any price. Nevertheless I kept it here and fixed the issue. I also simplified the usage of the arrows, I do not see a point in repeating `{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}` several times, IMHO it is much simpler to say `>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}` if all arrows should be of that type.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 8mm and 44mm,
    start chain = A going below,
    oh no/.style = {inner sep=0pt, rounded corners,scale=pi,
        on chain=A},
    >={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},  
    arr/.style = {color=#1, ultra thick,->}
    ]
    \node[oh no,alice]  {};  % A-1
    \node[oh no,alice] {};
    \node[oh no,bob]  {};% A-3
    %
    \node[oh no,above right=of A-1.east,label=below:4]{\faFileTextO};         % A-4
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]  {\faFileTextO};
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]  {\faFileTextO};
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]   {\faFileTextO};    % A-7
% 
    \draw[red, ultra thick,<->]  (A-4.east) to [bend left=45] (A-6.east);    


    \foreach \i in {4,6,7}
    {\draw[arr=black] (A-1.east) -- (A-\i);}

    \draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-4);
    \draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-6);
    \foreach \i in {6}
    {\draw[arr=purple!50!gray] (A-3.east) -- (A-\i);}
    %
    \draw[arr=orange,densely dashed] (A-4) -- (A-3);
    %\draw[arr=brown,densely dashed] (A-7) -- (A-3);

    \draw[arr=orange, ultra thick,dashed,->]  (A-7) to [bend left=45] (A-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks as expected! Sharp! One question, is it possible to make the arrows touch `\faFileTextO`

Comment: @NaveganTeX Sure. just drop `outer xsep=2mm`.