# Trying to plot two figures changing the embedded figures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw these two plots:

[image]
[image]

Instead of having those images, I would like to use the `\usepackage{fontawesome}` package, where I can choose multiple icons as described here [Thefontawesomepackage](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf).

MWE (Credits to [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513007/185467))

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 8mm and 44mm,
    start chain = A going below,
    oh no/.style = {inner sep=0pt, rounded corners,scale=pi,
        on chain=A},
    >={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},  
    arr/.style = {color=#1, ultra thick,->}
    ]
    \node[oh no,alice]  {};  % A-1
    \node[oh no,alice] {};
    \node[oh no,bob]  {};% A-3
    %
    \node[oh no,above right=of A-1.east,label=below:4]{\faFileTextO};         % A-4
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]  {\faFileTextO};
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]  {\faFileTextO};
    \node[oh no,label=below:4]   {\faFileTextO};    % A-7
% 
    \draw[red, ultra thick,<->]  (A-4.east) to [bend left=45] (A-6.east);    


    \foreach \i in {4,6,7}
    {\draw[arr=black] (A-1.east) -- (A-\i);}

    \draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-4);
    \draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-6);
    \foreach \i in {6}
    {\draw[arr=purple!50!gray] (A-3.east) -- (A-\i);}
    %
    \draw[arr=orange,densely dashed] (A-4) -- (A-3);
    %\draw[arr=brown,densely dashed] (A-7) -- (A-3);

    \draw[arr=orange, ultra thick,dashed,->]  (A-7) to [bend left=45] (A-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I recommend using a `matrix`. You will have to replace the symbols by whatever you had in mind.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \node[alice,label=above:User A,scale=2](alice){};
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,right=3em of alice,row sep=1em,
 column 1/.style={column sep=3em},column 4/.style={column sep=3em},
 cells={nodes={font=\Huge}},
 column 6/.style={nodes={font=\normalsize\sffamily,yshift=1em}}] (mat) {
 \faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 1 \\
 \faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 2 \\
 \faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 3 \\
 \faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 4 \\
 };
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\draw[very thick,green!60!black] (alice) -- (mat-\X-1) (mat-\X-1) -- (mat-\X-2);}
 \path[nodes={align=center}] 
  (mat.north-|mat-1-1) node[above] {Similars of\\ User A}
  (mat.north-|mat-1-2.west) -- (mat.north-|mat-1-4.east) 
   node[midway,above] {Items of\\  \dots} 
  (mat.north-|mat-1-5.west) -- (mat.north-|mat-1-6.east) 
   node[midway,above] {Counts \& Rank} ;
 \draw[line width=1mm,-latex] (mat.center-|mat-1-4.east) --
  (mat.center-|mat-1-5.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily]
 \node[alice,label=above:User A,scale=2](alice){};
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,right=3em of alice,row sep=1em,
 column 1/.style={column sep=3em},column 4/.style={column sep=3em},
 cells={nodes={font=\Huge}},cells={every label/.style={font=\normalsize}},
 column 6/.style={nodes={font=\normalsize\sffamily,yshift=1em}}] (mat) {
 |[label=below:1]|\faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 1 \\
 |[label=below:2]|\faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 2 \\
 |[label=below:3]|\faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 3 \\
 |[label=below:4]|\faLinux & \faOptinMonster & \faSuitcase & \faUserSecret & \faUser & 4 \\
 };
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\draw[very thick,green!60!black] (alice) -- (mat-\X-1) (mat-\X-1) -- (mat-\X-2);}
 \path[nodes={align=center}] 
  (mat.north-|mat-1-1) node[above] {Similars of\\ User A}
  (mat.north-|mat-1-2.west) -- (mat.north-|mat-1-4.east) 
   node[midway,above] {Items of\\  \dots} 
  (mat.north-|mat-1-5.west) -- (mat.north-|mat-1-6.east) 
   node[midway,above] {Counts \& Rank} ;
 \draw[line width=1mm,-latex] (mat.center-|mat-1-4.east) --
  (mat.center-|mat-1-5.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! If I want to add labels to each duck/penguin I do it by `label:below:____`

Comment: @NaveganTeX Added.